# Jenkins, Gradle, Spring and Java 8 - very slow Java compile

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, gradle

Working on a new Jenkins(1.650)/Gradle(2.11) build for a Spring Framework 3 application that is going to run on Java 8.  The build was running on a VM with Centos 7.2.1511 installed.

While attempting to compile with Java 8u74 (oracle/linux/x64), we observed a 2 hour build time for compiling 6 classes.  Upon testing the war file produced by the build, we realized that Spring 3 and Java 8 don't see eye to eye.  We reverted to compiling with JDK 1.7.0_79 (the only change made), and the build ran in 23 seconds.

Any thoughts on why this happened?

Comment: Have a look at the following comment - it might be related to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977206/running-a-java-application-with-spring-boot-and-gradle-on-digitalocean#comment57684758_34977206 - tools for debugging such an issue would be `jstack` and/or `strace`.

Comment: Spring 3 and Java 8 are not compatible.  End of story, enough said.  It was faster to upgrade to Spring 4 than sit through the compile again.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278878/java-8-spring-compatibility